# Flexbox fluid horizontal scrolling

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a homepage (horizontal scrolling website) that will follow a design of 1 column 1 row, 1 column 2 rows, 1 column 3 row, then looping through. Is there a way to target using display flex but without the spot and stripe class that I have used.

This will be easier to follow within our template if we can remove the classes. This site will be horizontal scrolling to, so that will need to come into account for the design.

Design concept:
[image: Design concept]

```css
.tiles {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.tiles-list {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  padding: 0;
}

.lightbox {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
    width: 33.33vw;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.spot {
    flex: 1 1 50vh;
    height: auto;
    flex-basis:100%;
}
.strip {
    flex: 1 1 50vh;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="tiles">
    <div class="tiles-list">
        <div class="lightbox">
            <div class="spot" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="lightbox">
            <div class="spot">
                <div class="blog-detail">
                    test
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="strip">
                <div class="blog-detail">
                    test
                </div>              
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="lightbox">
            <div class="strip">
                <div class="blog-detail">
                    test
                </div>                      
            </div>
            <div class="spot">
                <div class="blog-detail">
                    test
                </div>                      
            </div>
            <div class="strip">
                <div class="blog-detail">
                    test
                </div>                      
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="lightbox">
            <div class="spot" >
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Checkout this snippet https://codepen.io/alowenthal/pen/JGGJOP

Comment: Hi Vivek, this is not correct as the design is slightly different, for example the first box is 100% height. Please see design concept link. thanks!!

Comment: so you want to *remove* the `spot` and `stripe` classes from the markup and target it using CSS selectors? is that the requirement?

Comment: Yes that is the requirement please

Comment: @brad I just provided an example to you to check. I didn't provided your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just replace your `.spot` and `.stripe` classes with this - `.lightbox > *` will target the *first descendants of `lightbox`:

```
.lightbox > * {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

Note that `flex: 1 1 100%` is sufficient to cover the *flexing* of the `lightbox` child elements. See demo below:

```css
.tiles {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.tiles-list {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  padding: 0;
}

.lightbox {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 33.33vw;
}

.lightbox > * { /* CHANGED */
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="tiles">
  <div class="tiles-list">
    <div class="lightbox">
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="lightbox">
      <div>
        <div class="blog-detail">
          test
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="blog-detail">
          test
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="lightbox">
      <div>
        <div class="blog-detail">
          test
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="blog-detail">
          test
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="blog-detail">
          test
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="lightbox">
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can use the newer [`CSS Grid layout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) to simplify the *markup* and styling by using a 6-row grid that *auto-flows* in columns - see demo below:

```css
.tiles {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.tiles-list {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  padding: 0;
}

.tiles-list>* {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 33.33vw;
}

.tiles-list>*:nth-child(6n+1) {
  grid-row: span 6;
}

.tiles-list>*:nth-child(6n+2),
.tiles-list>*:nth-child(6n+3) {
  grid-row: span 3;
}

.tiles-list>*:nth-child(6n+4),
.tiles-list>*:nth-child(6n+5),
.tiles-list>*:nth-child(6n+6) {
  grid-row: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="tiles">
  <div class="tiles-list">
    <div></div>
    <div class="blog-detail">test</div>
    <div class="blog-detail">test</div>
    <div class="blog-detail">test</div>
    <div class="blog-detail">test</div>
    <div class="blog-detail">test</div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Flex

```css
.tiles {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 90vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
.tiles .tile {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
}
.tiles .tile:nth-child(6n+1) {
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 1);
}
.tiles .tile:nth-child(6n+2), .tiles .tile:nth-child(6n+3) {
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 2);
}
.tiles .tile:nth-child(6n+4), .tiles .tile:nth-child(6n+5), .tiles .tile:nth-child(6n+6) {
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 3);
}

.tiles .tile:nth-child(6n + 1) {
  background-color: #000000;
}
.tiles .tile:nth-child(6n + 2) {
  background-color: #CD0000;
}
.tiles .tile:nth-child(6n + 3) {
  background-color: #1C0174;
}
.tiles .tile:nth-child(6n + 4) {
  background-color: #F601CB;
}
.tiles .tile:nth-child(6n + 5) {
  background-color: #010600;
}
.tiles .tile:nth-child(6n + 6) {
  background-color: #137400;
}
```

```html
<div class="tiles">
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
</div>
```

Using Grid

```css
.tiles {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: calc(100% / 3);
  grid-template-rows: calc(100% / 6);
  grid-auto-columns: calc(100% / 3);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  height: 90vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
.tiles .tile:nth-child(6n + 1) {
  grid-row-end: span 6;
}
.tiles .tile:nth-child(6n + 2), .tiles .tile:nth-child(6n + 3) {
  grid-row-end: span 3;
}
.tiles .tile:nth-child(6n + 4), .tiles .tile:nth-child(6n + 5), .tiles .tile:nth-child(6n + 6) {
  grid-row-end: span 2;
}
.tiles .tile:nth-child(6n + 1) {
  background-color: #000000;
}
.tiles .tile:nth-child(6n + 2) {
  background-color: #CD0000;
}
.tiles .tile:nth-child(6n + 3) {
  background-color: #1C0174;
}
.tiles .tile:nth-child(6n + 4) {
  background-color: #F601CB;
}
.tiles .tile:nth-child(6n + 5) {
  background-color: #010600;
}
.tiles .tile:nth-child(6n + 6) {
  background-color: #137400;
}
```

```html
<div class="tiles">
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
</div>
```